# liveserver websocket connection error

Tags: websocket, npm-live-server

I'm hoping someone else has run accross this issue and can offer some help.
I'm worried that I messed up my system because of something I installed or changed, I'm running out of ideas.

I've been using **Liveserver** without issue for awhile but more recently it's loaded but won't refresh the browser due to an error with websockets.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

It does open the browser once I've run the command in a command promt, but after that it never refreshes.
I am using Google Chrome, here is the console error message I get.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080//ws' failed: One or more
>   reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 0

Running Windows 7 on a PC where it's worked before without an issue.
I've taken the steps of completely uninstalling Nodejs, reinstalling it with no change.

Note: At one point I was getting path error regarding PYTHON and then VC errors possibly regarding Visual Studio, just hoping that might help.